# Generate random numbers from a Poisson distribution with defined range [min, max]

Tags: r, random, poisson

I would like to draw 100 random numbers from a Poisson distribution with a mean of 0.5, ranging from 0 to 10.

Using the `rpois(n = 100, lambda = 0.50)` function, I can obtain the random numbers from the Poisson distribution, but I am unable to specify the min/max values.

Any way of doing this in R?

A bit more context: In a dataset, my dependent variable has the properties mentioned above (mean, min, max values), and I would like to estimate some models with simulated data for my dependent variable.

Edit: My dependent variable (for which I want to simulate the random numbers in addition to the observed values) is neither truncated nor censored. However, I should note that its standard deviation is 1, i.e., the variance is not equal to the mean of 0.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the Poisson distribution has infinite support. So if you are limiting to a defined ranged, you're not really sampling from a Poisson distribution any more. You could draw from a standard Poisson and then just filter the results, but then you need to be careful how you interpret those values.

Comment: Is this a truncated or censored distribution? Otherwise, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you. I would be willing to sacrifice interpretability if the numbers satisfy my criteria. That is, it doesn't necessarily need to be a Poisson distribution (in my data, the standard deviation is 1, i.e., not equal to the mean of 0.5). I guess I might need to use a different distribution or filter the results as you suggest.

Comment: If you don't know the actual distribution, why not just [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) from the existing dataset?  That will preserve the mean and variance of your actual data, and not require unrealistic or unsupportable distributional modeling assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have limited number of items to sample, just make probabilities to follow Poisson and sample

Along the lines

```
l <- 0.5

x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

p <- rep(0, length(x)) # probabilities

s <- 0.0
for (k in x) {
    p[k+1] = l**k * exp(-l) / gamma(k+1)
    s <- s + p[k+1]
}

p = p / s # normalization

print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
print(sample(x, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=p))
```

Comment: That will give a truncated Poisson, but it won't have the desired standard deviation of 1.  I generated 10000 values using this approach, and came up with s ~= 0.707.

Comment: @pjs Yes, with λ=0.5 we will be getting very little outside 0...10 range. It would be pretty close to real Poisson with mean = λ = 0.5 and sd = sqrt(λ) = 0.707. For sd = 1 one has to widen the distribution. Basically, change probabilities such that mean=0.5 (one condition), sd=1 (second condition) and, I would guess, third condition would be p_k > p_{k+1}. For 11 probabilities should be a lot of solutions satisfying above conditions. Might be more conditions to keep it close to Poisson, e.g. p_{k+1}/p_k ~ λ/k